# Requested ship date

Tags: writing, word-order

A company has the words *This order will ship on 9/14/2010 from our Virginia location* on their website.  The user could request a ship date in the future.

The internal, recommended replacement is *This order is requested to ship on 9/14/2010 from our Virginia location* but the readability of the statement is in question.

What is the correct way to combine a requested ship date and a location statement in a single sentence?

Comment: Does it have to be a single sentence?

Comment: Not if it reads well and is concise.

Comment: A "requested ship date": Is this the date that a customer has asked an order be shipped out to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "This order is requested to ship on 9/14/2010 from our Virginia location" but the readability of the statement is in question.

The problem here seems to be that the sentence reads as if the order itself has been requested to do something, when in fact the customer has requested the *company* to ship the order on *date* from *location*.

You could turn it into an active sentence:

> The customer has requested shipment on *date* from *location*.

Comment: The active sentence was deemed most readable.  Thank you to everyone for their insight!

Comment: @davidj: good news, a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

This order is scheduled to ship on 9/14/2010 from our Virginia location, per customer request.

Comment: The statement cannot be an implied guarantee.  This one is quite readable, but implies guarantee.  However, this order MAY ship is right out as well.  :-)

Comment: I see, however "may ship" starts to sound slippery. So perhaps "is scheduled to ship".

Comment: This sentence also seems needlessly complex, which unfortunately means that it's business-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I would like *Shipment from our Virginia location on 9/14/2010, as user requested.*

Comment: Is that a complete sentence?

Comment: @Justin: No, it isn't. And that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The order has a requested ship date of 9/14 from our Virginia location.

Answer (score -1):

Correct:
The order has been requested to be shipped on 9/14/2010 from our Virginia location.

"BE" indicates future.

Incorrect:
The order has been requested to ship on 9/14/2010 from our Virginia location